# Foreach in json array returns an array but not considered as such and can't iterate it

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a json array (dataArray) sent from js to php using JSON.stringuify.

I'm getting the output after using json_decode that object like this:

```
$resp = json_decode($dataArray,true);
error_log($resp);
```

Log:

```
[{"id":"0","name":"JOAO"},{"id":"1","name":"TONI"},{"id":"2","name":"ANA"}]
```

I'm trying to get the **id** and **name** values from each element in that array.

Using foreach returns an error since the object is not considered as an array...
So I tried casting it to an array and then use it in the foreach, and it's size is still 1:

```
$arr = (array) $res;
error_log(sizeof($arr[0]));
foreach ($arr[0] as $dt) {
    error_log($dt);
}
```

This returns the "full sized 1 array"

```
[{"id":"0","name":"JOAO"},{"id":"1","name":"TONI"},{"id":"2","name":"ANA"}]
```

and if I try `error_log($dt->id)` I don't get any results...

I'm not understanding why this is not being considered as an array.

Comment: If you're managing to call `error_log` (which expects a string) without any issues, it sounds like your data might be double-encoded? Try `json_decode(json_decode($dataArray),true);`

Comment: What does `var_dump($resp)` show?

Comment: Or just show what `$dataArray` contains.

Comment: dataArray contains exacty that array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you need the `html_entity_decode()` before decoding it,

```
$data = html_entity_decode($dataArray);
$output = json_decode($data,true);
foreach ($output as $key=>$dt) {
    echo "id=".$dt['id']," & name=".$dt['name'].PHP_EOL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If do as suggested:

```
$data = html_entity_decode($dataTypesArray);
$output = json_decode($data,true);

//or json_decode(json_decode($dataArray),true);
error_log($output);

foreach ($output as $dt) {
    error_log($dt);
}
```

I get `error_log() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given` so I used `error_log(json_encode($dt));` I now I get the individual jsons but still no sucess logginf the ID and name...

Comment: have a look on my answer again, I've edited it to log the id and name value.